# How to serve uploaded image using Sanic?

Tags: python-3.x, sanic

I have successfully uploaded image in a certain directory in my project using Sanic. The code that I used to upload image is as follows:

```
class ImageUploadAPI(HTTPMethodView):
    async def post(self, request):
        access_token = get_token_from_header(request.headers)
        token = decode_token(access_token)
        user_id = token.get('sub')
        upload_file = request.files.get('image')
        log_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'pictures')
        if not os.path.exists(log_path):
            os.makedirs(log_path)

        if not upload_file:
            res = {'status': 'no file uploaded'}
            return json(res, status=404)

    # if not valid_file_type(upload_file.name, upload_file.type):
    #     res = {'status': 'invalid file type'}
    #     return json(res, status=400)
        elif not valid_file_size(upload_file.body):
            res = {'status': 'invalid file size'}
            return json(res, status=400)
        else:
            file_path = f"{log_path}/{str(datetime.now())}.{upload_file.name.split('.')[1]}"
            await write_file(file_path, upload_file.body)
            await apps.db.users.update_one({'_id': ObjectId(user_id)}, {"$set": {
            "nid_front": upload_file.name
            }})
            return json({'status': 'image uploaded successfully'})
```

In this process I have saved the `upload_file.name` in a `user` field.
Now to serve the uploaded image, I have accessed the following url(*as i am in local server*) http://localhost:8000/10414532_479247615552487_2110029531698825823_n.jpg
but it doesn't show the image instead showing that,

```
Error: Requested URL /10414532_479247615552487_2110029531698825823_n.jpg not found
```

How can I serve the uploaded image ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution reading [Sanic static files](https://sanic.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sanic/static_files.html).
I have used the *blueprint* option to serve my uploaded images as:

```
static_file_bp = Blueprint('static', url_prefix='/files')
static_file_bp.static('/static', './uploads')
```

Comment: Consider accepting your own answer to help other users who have similar problem. The can see problem has a working solution.